# How to disable automatic wifi connection on wlan0 (Stretch)?

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch

I'm building wifi-router (hostapd, dnsmasq) on Raspberry pi 3 (Raspberrian Stretch). 
Wlan0 configured as static IP adapter for hostapd.
It works fine for eth0 -> wlan0 direction. In this case, wpa_supplicant is empty.

But I cannot share internet from another wifi adapter wlan1 -> wlan0. In this case, wpa_supplicant has network settings and wlan0 connects to the source network.

I had no such problem on raspbian jessie.

How to force wlan0 to not automatically connect to wifi networks?

---

if wpa_supplicant contains password ifconfig returns following output:

```
root@raspi3:/home/pi/vrouter# wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.53  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 192.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::69cb:7b25:d42b:e33f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:53:2d:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 266  bytes 50171 (48.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 47  bytes 7212 (7.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

if wpa_supplicant contains no passwords ifconfig returns proper wlan0 setting:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
        inet6 fe80::e460:9b98:5dea:599d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:53:4d:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 33  bytes 4966 (4.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**wpa_supplicant.conf:**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="my_internet"
    psk="qwerty123"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

**interfaces** contains only one line:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

**dhcpcd.conf:**

```
hostname
clientid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier
# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.0.0.1/8
static routers=10.0.0.1
```

**dnsmasq.conf:**

```
no-resolv

interface=wlan0
except-interface=wlan1
except-interface=wlan2
except-interface=wlan3
except-interface=eth0

dhcp-range=10.0.0.3,10.0.0.20,12h

server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
log-queries
```

**hostapd.conf:**

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=Raspberry3
channel=6
country_code=US
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
hw_mode=g
#auth
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=Myau1Kot
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP 
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

# control
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2

ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

Comment: Disable (better remove completely) dhcpcd and configure your network manually.  You will have more control over it.

Comment: I don't link this idea because I'd like to have dhcpcd for wlan1 to configure different adapters and wifi networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your objectives by a combination of the following 2 settings (extract from [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) ]

### Prevent `dhcpcd` from configuring an interface

This is often done to enable the Pi to act as an [Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) (which needs to be configured using other files), while allowing normal `DHCP` configuration on other interfaces.

Add `denyinterfaces wlan0` to the end of the file (but above any other added interface lines).

### Use different wpa_supplicant files

It is possible to configure dhcpcd to use different wpa_supplicant.conf files for a specific wireless interface.

Create a file named `wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` e.g. `wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` will only be used by `wlan0`

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` will be used for any other wireless interfaces.

Comment: "denyinterfaces wlan0" doesn't work for me. But creating wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf with without any networks works fine.